# I've to display output of print_r() into a table but I can't do.If I store that array in simple varibale then i'll be able to print.Where is mistake?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, printing

php code to store array data

```
$series_ids = [];
for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($j_decode); $i < $iMax; $i++) {
  $series_ids[] = $j_decode[$i]["series_id"];
 $s_id=$series_ids[];
}
echo $s_id;
```

PS I don't want to use print_r. I need to display the result in table

Comment: It's unclear what the exact issue is or how it relates to tables. Please give more context to the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.